# Can i run Ubuntu WSL2 on a VPS which runs Windows Server 2022 Datacenter

Tags: windows, virtualization, vps, virtualbox

I want to use a 8GB RAM, 4 VCore VPS Server which my hoster Contabo  offers with Windows Server 2022 Datacenter image.

This is for a build server that should generate executables for Windows and Linux. Cross compilation is an always buggy and messy hell so i want to use WSL2 on this system to do the Linux builds too and save the money and energy/CO2  for just another VPS.

Is this possible? What with other solutions like virtual box? Do they allow nested virtual machines with different operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your hoster supports nested virtualization. WSL2 and VitrualBox will work on the virtual Windows 2022